# JPEG SOS specification

Tags: jpeg

I am parsing a JPG in java byte by byte.  I am then writing same image byte by byte, and I have come across an oddity.  I have tried looking at the spec but I see no reference.

At the end of the SOS section there are three bytes that most sources say 'skip'.  But if I write 0x00,0x00,0x00 then java(fx) complains about an invalid value.  If I write 0x000x3f0x00 then there is no complaint. (the three byte sequence is what was produced by GIMP in the original file)

I came across an indirect reference to this [in the GoLang repo](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/5f7bec693d3d383061586d6f29f4fea2648399a7)

```
//  - the bytes "\x00\x3f\x00". Section B.2.3 of the spec says that for
//    sequential DCTs, those bytes (8-bit Ss, 8-bit Se, 4-bit Ah, 4-bit Al)
//    should be 0x00, 0x3f, 0x00<<4 | 0x00.
```

My question is should I just write 0x3f at this position, or does the value depend upon something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a sequential JPEG scan this value has no meaning. The standard says to set it to 63 but that tells the decoder nothing. You have to process all 64 DCT coefficients in a sequential scan.

In a progressive scan this value means A LOT.

Comment: Thanks.  This is a sequential scan, and I can do the complete cycle read, write, read with no problem. Maybe the jpg parser hiding somewhere behind javafx.scene.image.Image is very strict.  But your answer helps a lot as it means that I just need to put 63 in this spot until I start handling progressive jpgs.  I did wonder what the three bytes were there for if everyone just skips them.  Now I know. Thanks.